# synthax highlighter - editing the highlighted text in textarea element

Tags: jquery, textarea, syntaxhighlighter

I have implemented Alex Gorbatchev's Synthax highlighter, and it's working great, however when the user double clicks on the highlighted text(which by then became a div from textarea), it enters the edit mode(generates nameless textarea on the fly with highlited text data in it). I have created a button, and performing click event trying to grab the newly entered/edited text from it to rePOST it through ajax, but i keep getting either old text that was in textarea(which turned into a highlited div) or 'undefined'. I'm using jQuery to get the newly entered text but have no luck. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
extends layout
block content
  h2=d.title
    a(class='button', href='/documents/' + d._id + '/edit') Edit
  p
    a(href='/documents', class='button')
      &larr; All Documents
  script(type="text/javascript")
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    SyntaxHighlighter.config.tagName = "textarea";

  form(name="form1") 
    div(style="width:800px; margin:0 auto; border: 2px grey solid;")  
      textarea(class="brush: js;", style="width:800px;", readonly="true", id = "srcText", disabled)
        =d.data || ''

  button(id="submit", class='button')

  script
    $("#submit").click(function (e) {
      console.log("boom");
      var dId = '#{d._id}';
      var dData = $("textarea").val(); // << -- problem here cant obtain the value
      console.log("DATA  is: ", dData);
      var updateDocumentIdPath = "/documents/" + dId + "/update";
      $.ajax({
        url: updateDocumentIdPath, 
        type: "POST",  
        data: {"data": dData},
        success: function (data) {
          console.log("success");
          console.log(data);
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log("error");
        },
        complete: function () {
        }
      }); // END ajax
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

For getting the data, you are using `$("textarea").val();` which returns the value of the *first* `textarea` in the `document`. Docs: http://api.jquery.com/val/

What you need is something like: `$("textarea:last").val();`. This will return the value of the last `textarea` in the `document`. Assuming it will be the last `textarea` in the `document` since you mentioned its being dynamically inserted before switching to edit mode.

Comment: thank you for answer!, still this variable is undefined. I think, after temporary textarea gous out of focus, the value gets lost instantly :(, in fact ive inspected element and clicked on/out of textarea, the textarea tag disappears as soon as focusout occurs.